# Using JMF on Mac OSX

Tags: java, video, jmf, mpeg

I'm trying to use JMF (Java Media Framework) to play a video. I've tried sample code from four different websites now. I'm using a Mac running Lion.

Everytime I load an mpg file I have, I get:

```
Unable to handle format: MPEG, 352x240, FrameRate=29.9, Length=126720
```

What does this mean? Are there problems with JMF? I'm using the cross platform version.

Comment: See [Simple MPEG Video Stream player, cross-platform, in java, via NetBeans + Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647296/simple-mpeg-video-stream-player-cross-platform-in-java-via-netbeans-swing).

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: Hence why it's a comment, *not an answer*.

Comment: The actual error means it can't handle that format out of the box, which is quite possibly because of [software patents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_LA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cross-platform version will probably not support too many formats. There are [performance packs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html) which might help. But there isn't a performance pack for MAC and probably never will be.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Jffmpeg](http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/), which provides MPEG codecs (among many [other formats](http://jffmpeg.sourceforge.net/formats.html)) for JMF.  However, bear in mind that the [last release](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jffmpeg/files/jffmpeg/) is 2006.

Another alternative if [FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net/index.php).